# Document management with sharepoint

Tags: document, access

I'm looking for a way to categorize and tag a large number of documents that will be part of a research project in Geophysics. There a few types of records, such as logs, rock testing and core analysis.

The metadata associated with each type of document is very different, but have a few items in common, such as "on/offshore" (choice menu), location (single line text) and lithology (choice menu).

Would it be possible for me to create separate **folders** with different classes of documents (and thus different metadata) and have each of the documents' first few columns (items in common) automatically transferred to a global folder displaying all of the documents? Granting access to different people would be nice, but not essential.

Would I be better off using access or Nuxeo instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is enough to get you started:

**Create content types for each type of document/record**

1. Create site columns for each of your pieces of metadata
2. Create content types for each document type
3. Add the appropriate site columns to each content type

**Set up your document library**

1. Create your document library
2. In your document library's settings, under Advanced Settings, enable Management of Content Types
3. Add all your content types to the document library

**Apply different permissions to each folder** (if I understood your requirement correctly)

1. Create the required folders in your document library
2. Break permission inheritance on each folder and apply unique permissions to each

**Create your desired views for your document library**

1. You might have one view for each document type. You can do this by applying a filter in your views on "ContentType is equal to ContentTypeName"
2. To see all documents in a flat view, create another view and in the view settings under the "Folders" group select "Show all items without folders".